# Getting User Identity from a POST Request in ASP.NET

Tags: python, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webforms

So my ASP.NET site is being hosted on an intranet. One of the things I need to do is to be able to get the active directory username of the person if they are trying to do a POST request through a simple API I have set up.

Currently I am very confused with my settings. In my web.config I have the following: `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

and in my applicationhost.config I have this:

```
            <authentication>

            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />

            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
            </windowsAuthentication>

            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
            </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>

        </authentication>
```

But if I turn off anonymous authentication it breaks all of my GET methods which I am calling via urllib2 in python and I am unable to access them (401 Forbidden).

What I really want is to be able to do something like this:

```
        string logonName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Whenever there is a POST request to the server and then compare that name against an active directory to see if they are in the group with the correct permissions to make the POST. Currently I have this working if I hardcode a username but whenever I send a POST request it always goes for anonymous authentication and returns `""` for the user.

So is there any way to grab *just* a username (no password needed) in my ASP.NET application? Should this be handled on the python side or is there an easy way to configure my settings to do it, if so, how?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using windows authentication then you should turn off anonymous authentication.

if you make the api call outside browser for example not from jquery, then it won't pass credentials to the api server.

what you may do, probably just turn off windows authentication and just pass the username as parameter of the api method, and you can use it to query AD.

Comment: This is what I figured I would have to do. I'll try this until a better solution comes along. Thanks.

Comment: just pay attention that it will make the authentication no longer secure since username only is not a secure token. maybe if you set an application password for that and let your phyton passes username and the password to the api will make more sense.